# Are there any French image board sites like the American 4chan?

Tags: ressources

Since I am from a non French speaking country it's hard to know any underground content.

Is there a French equivalent of 4chan?

Comment: Not a question about French language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*cable6*](http://cable6.net/) could be what you are looking for:

> *cable6* est un système de billet électronique simple basé sur l'échange
>   d'image où n'importe qui peut écrire un commentaire ou partager des
>   images. Les utilisateurs sont anonymes et n'ont besoin d'aucun compte
>   pour participer. De plus la modération est légère et offre une grande
>   liberté d'expression.
>
> Site réservé aux adultes, merci de lire les règles et la netiquette
>   avant de poster quoi que ce soit.
>
> *Planches*
>
> [...]

Comment: Merci à vous. C'est parfait.

Answer (score 0):

Either Cable6 or Jeuxvideo.com (especially the 15-18 part).