# Un site pour les traductions des menus et options windows ?

Tags: traduction, ressources, informatique

Question : Y a-t-il un site offrant des traductions des noms des options et services Windows ?

J'ai souvent un problème quand j'ai besoin de changer des options Windows et que je trouve des tutos en anglais, c'est pas toujours facile à utiliser. Par exemple

> Type "computer managment", then click "Services and applications"

Les options n'ont pas le même nom en français, et souvent si j'essaie de traduire moi-même j'obtiens pas du tout ce que Windows a traduit. C'est encore pire pour les services. Quand je dois désactiver un service dont le nom est donné en anglais et que j'ai la liste en français, impossible de le trouver, le nom est souvent très différent. Ex :
[image]

**Est-ce qu'il y a une ressource donnant la traduction officielle de microsoft des différents menus et services de windows ?**

<sub>J'espère que cette question n'est pas hors-sujet, j'ai vu des [questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12848/are-there-any-french-image-board-sites-like-the-american-4chan) dans le même genre donc ça devrait être bon.</sub>

Comment: I thought Super User was the place to ask questions about Windows.... This is a technical question, not a language question, or don't I understand the question ?

Comment: Pour moi la question est aussi légitimée par des listes comme [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24262/resources-to-verify-french-words-expressions-usage-grammar) — ah mais je vois que ton commentaire là exprime la même opinion ! Oui, pour wiki/meta peut-être. Mes propres instincts à propos de ce type de question ne sont pas encore assez développées, mais je trouve de telles listes utiles n'importe où elles finissent par se situer.

Comment: @AgentBaptiste Oui, la liste a été mieux faite là sur ELU. Mais pour cette question, je dirais qu'il y a définitivement un lien avec la langue ; une langue n'est que la somme de son histoire et des contextes ou on la parle ! « Suggérez svp une ressource pour vérifier les mots que je rencontre dans la littérature classique » ne te semblerait-elle être une question légitime ? Pour moi « ... que je rencontre en utilisant mon PC » a la même valeur même s'il ne s'agit que d'un petit domaine.

Comment: Et tout comme la réponse à la première devrait citer une autorité sur la littérature, celle-ci doit en citer une qui puisse donner les termes standards pour ce domaine. C'est l'un des contextes où on peut employer le français, soit conformément aux normes ou non, donc à mon avis il est utile de pouvoir voir ce qui s'est développé dans le domaine et comment le vérifier. (Cela n'est pas à dire ni que « ressource » ne différerait pas de « réponse » et donc devrait rester dans cette zone du site, ni que sur le forum Super User ou quoi que ce soit on n'aurait rien à dire là aussi à ce sujet.)

Comment: @AgentBaptiste Si, j'aurais dû consulter les ressources existantes avant de redisputer. Enfin je crois que dans l'ensemble on est d'accord sur cette question (toi avec moi et nous deux avec ce fil où Gilles demande et répond) : utile mais à reléguer à meta. Pour la philosophie de ce qui constitute une langue, à une autre occasion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft offre un « Portail linguistique » où on choisit les deux langues à comparer (y compris FR→EN et EN→FR), ainsi que le produit dans lequel le terme souhaité apparaîtrait :

> [Microsoft - Portail linguistique - Recherche terminologique](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/language)

Par exemple, si je cherche « computer management » de l'anglais vers le français dans tous les contextes, je vois que la traduction officielle est « gestion de l'ordinateur » :

[image: computer management]

Notez que les traductions semblent malheureusement toujours être présentées dans la direction EN→FR (même si on essaie « gestion de l'ordinateur » du français vers l'anglais), mais comme le terme français est quand même le terme clé pour la recherche, ce n'est pas *trop* grave.

Vu que les produits Microsoft ou établissent ou partagent souvent la terminologie standardisée du secteur, cet outil est encore plus utile qu'il ne semble.

Comment: Merci ! C'est exactement ce que je cherchais, et ça a l'air de marcher aussi pour les services :)

Comment: J'ai l'impression qu'ils ont changé leur architecture et que le lien est mort, voilà [le nouveau](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/language).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Merci, mis à jour